# Passing value from another function to another function on PHP

Tags: php, class, function

I have two class separated on the difference page. What I want to do is to save a value returned from a function and passing it to the another function. I have the code below:

**Class publicfunction (on publicfunction.php)**

```
class publicfunction {
  public static function getqs() { 
    $qs = array();
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $qs);
}}
```

**Class be_mstpublc (on be_mstpublc.php)**

```
class be_mstpublc {
  public static function setmstpublcpgtitle() { 
    if(!empty($qs['mst'])) {
        switch($qs['mst']) {
            case 'A': 
                $pagetitle = "A";
                break;
}}}}
```

Then on another page to implement the function above:

```
call_user_func(array('publicfunction', 'getqs'));
call_user_func(array('be_mstpublc', 'setmstpublcpgtitle'));
echo $pagetitle;
```

But it doesn't return any value.

Any ideas? Thanks..

**-- EDIT --**

I have passed a value on the URL, i.e.: **localhost/test/index.php?mst=A**

Comment: Where does setmstpublcpgtitle() find the $qs variable?

Comment: @periklis: How can I do that? Doesn't the code above to implement the function first called the 'getqs' function?

Comment: Yes, but it's out of scope. deceze below explains what you should do

Comment: Could I ask why you're calling the methods with such a nonobvious mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `return` the value, otherwise it doesn't go anywhere:

```
public static function getqs() { 
    $qs = array();
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $qs);

    return $qs;
}
```

Then, accept it as a parameter:

```
public static function setmstpublcpgtitle($qs) {
  ...
}
```

Then, pass it:

```
$qs = publicfunction::getqs();
be_mstpublc::setmstpublcpgtitle($qs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of variable scope. The method `publicfunction::qs()` is implicitly declaring a *local* variable called `$qs`. It is not accessible outside this method.

Normally, if you put storage in a class, you have multiple methods in the same class for setting and retrieving it. One solution is to put `setmstpublcpgtitle` into class `publicfunction`. However, this second method has the same problem. It needs to return `$pagetitle`, not just set it.